# SQL single select to modify the second string occurance in all wordpress posts

Tags: mysql, database, string, wordpress

I'm trying to use a single SQL SELECT statement in order to update all the posts contents in a worpress database.

For each individual post, I need to update a specific string value that is randomly positioned within the post body. This value is not unique, hence it occurs several times within the content, but I only need to update the second occurence.

Below, I've got the code to to so, for a single post, and I'd need some help to extend it in order to do it for the entire posts table in the database.

```
SET @pos=2; // this is the occurrence index

SET @str := (SELECT `post_content` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE ID = 1); // this is a specific post identified by the ID

SET @search='1234'; // this is the test string I'm looking for

// 4321 is the replacement value of 1234 search sting above

// post update sql query

UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,@search,@pos),'4321',SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,@search,(@pos-1-(LENGTH(@str)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@str,@search,'')))/LENGTH(@search))))) WHERE ID = 1;
```

Now this works perfectly as a query for a single post identified by an ID, however I'm not so sure as to how to extend it to be applied across all posts in the wordpress database, and yet use a single sql query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting a specific post into @str and manipulating it in update query do it directly to 'post_content'. (`@str` replaced by `post_content` and `WHERE ID = 1` removed)

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`post_content`,@search,@pos),'4321',SUBSTRING_INDEX(`post_content`,@search,(@pos-1-(LENGTH(`post_content`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`post_content`,@search,'')))/LENGTH(@search)))));
```

Comment: It works like a charm @chandimak. I do't know why it hadn't previously worked when I tried with post_content. Must have been a typo. Meanwhile, I ended up with a slightly more complicated version that works, but is a little heavier on the database than your version:

    UPDATE `wp_posts`, (SELECT `post_content` as test FROM `wp_posts`) AS str SET      `post_content` =  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`str`.test,@search,@pos),'4321',SUBSTRING_INDEX(`str`.test,@search,(@pos-1-(LENGTH(`str`.test)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`str`.test,@search,'')))/LENGTH(@search)))) WHERE `str`.test =`wp_posts`.post_content;

Comment: I didn't go through the logic of your update query. Just made it capable of handling all posts. So, I have no idea that, whether this could be the ideal solution or not. Anyway, glad you could solve the problem.